# Google Docs: Cannot export/download user's document using administrative access/impersonation (forbidden 403) in python

Tags: google-docs-api

I have read this thoroughly: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#using_google_apps_administrative_access_to_impersonate_other_domain_users
I have googled this to death.

So far I have been able to:

1. Authorise with:

   - clientLogin
   - OAuth tokens (using my domain key)
2. retrieve document feeds for all users in the domain (authorised either way in #1)
   I am using the "entry" from the feed to Export/Download documents and always get forbidden for other users for documents not shared with admin. The feed query I am using is like:
   `https://docs.google.com/feeds/userid@mydomain.com/private/full/?v=3`
   (I have tried with and without the ?v=3)

I have also tried adding the xoauth_requestor_id (which I have also seen in posts as xoauth_requestor), both on the uri, and as a client property: `client.xoauth_requestor_id = ...`

Code fragments:

Client Login (using administrator credentials):

```
client.http_client.debug = cfg.get('HTTPDEBUG')
client.ClientLogin( cfg.get('ADMINUSER'), cfg.get('ADMINPASS'), 'HOSTED' )
```

OAuth:

```
client.http_client.debug = cfg.get('HTTPDEBUG')
client.SetOAuthInputParameters( gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1, cfg.get('DOMAIN'), cfg.get('APPS.SECRET') )
oatip = gdata.auth.OAuthInputParams( gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1, cfg.get('DOMAIN'), cfg.get('APPS.SECRET') )
oat = gdata.auth.OAuthToken( scopes = cfg.get('APPS.%s.SCOPES' % section), oauth_input_params = oatip )
oat.set_token_string( cfg.get('APPS.%s.TOKEN' % section) )
client.current_token = oat
```

Once the feed is retrieved:

```
# pathname eg whatever.doc
client.Export(entry, pathname)
# have also tried
client.Export(entry, pathname, extra_params = { 'v': 3 } )
# and tried
client.Export(entry, pathname, extra_params = { 'v': 3, 'xoauth_requestor_id': 'admin@mydomain.com' } )
```

Any suggestions, or pointers as to what I am missing here?
Thanks

Comment: If this question is answered, can you mark it answered?  Also, please post a new question with steps to reproduce the other 401s/403s you mentioned in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close to having a correct implementation.  In your example above, you had:

```
client.Export(entry, pathname, extra_params = { 'v': 3, 'xoauth_requestor_id': 'admin@mydomain.com' } )
```

xoauth_requestor_id must be set to the user you're impersonating.  Also what you need is to use 2-Legged OAuth 1.0a with the xoauth_requestor_id set either in the token or in the client.

```
import gdata.docs.client
import gdata.gauth

import tempfile


# Replace with values from your Google Apps domain admin console
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''

# Set this to the user you're impersonating, NOT the admin user
username = 'userid@mydomain.com'
destination = tempfile.mkstemp()

token = gdata.gauth.TwoLeggedOAuthHmacToken(
    consumer_key, consumer_secret, username)
# Setting xoauth_requestor_id in the DocsClient constructor is not required
# because we set it in the token above, but I'm showing it here in case your
# token is constructed via some other mechanism and you need another way to
# set xoauth_requestor_id.
client = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient(
    auth_token=token, xoauth_requestor_id=username)
# Replace this with the resource your application needs
resource = client.GetAllResources()[0]
client.DownloadResource(resource, path)
print 'Downloaded %s to %s' % (resource.title.text, destination)
```

Here is the reference in the source code to the TwoLeggedOAuthHmacToken class:

1. http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/gauth.py#1062

And here are the references in the source code that provide the xoauth_requestor_id constructor parameter (read these in order):

1. http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/atom/client.py#42
2. http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/atom/client.py#179
3. http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/client.py#136

Comment: Thanks Vic. Much more success now. Still a handful of files with either 401 or 403, but it is likely for another reason